# Finding Modulus and Argument for Complex Number $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assume the Complex Number $z$ has argument $$\pi $$ and modulus $$\sqrt{3} $$ how would i find argument and modulus for $$-2iz$$ i already know the correct answer for this(it's from an old test) but i don't know how its calculated. I know how to find modulus and argument but im not sure about this exact math problem. Any help is greatly appreciated, please tell me if i should provide more info.

Comment: According to the given data $z=\sqrt{3}e^{i\pi}=\sqrt{3}(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi)=?.$ Also multiplying a complex number by a real number is just a scaling (and changing the direction, if negative), while multiplying a complex by $i$ amounts to rotate it $\pi/2$ radians in counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: Well, all the information that was given in the test is what i originally posted, so im not quite sure.

Comment: The given information is enough to determine this complex number, because $\cos\pi$ and $\sin\pi$ has specific values.

Comment: Sorry i meant im not quite sure i understand your solution.

Comment: If you know the both modulus and argument, then you can plot in on complex plane to find it exactly. Also if you know the trigonometric (or exponential) form of a complex number you can directly write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute the desired modulus and argument without evaluating $z$ (even though as indicated by @Chris, it is straightforward to do so):

- Since $\arg(-2i)=-\frac\pi2$ and $\arg(z)=\pi,$

  then working modulo $(-\pi,\pi],$ the principal argument of
  $(-2i\;z)$ is $$(-\frac\pi2)+(\pi)=\frac\pi2.$$
  Similarly, since $\arg(2i)=\frac\pi2,$

  then working modulo $(-\pi,\pi],$ the principal argument of $(2i\;z)$
  is $$(\frac\pi2)+(\pi)=-\frac\pi2.$$
- Since $|-2i|=2,\;\;|2i|=2\;$ and $|z|=\sqrt{3},$ then
  $$\left|-2i\;z\right|=2\sqrt{3}$$ and
  $$\left|2i\;z\right|=2\sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: is it possible to solve with reversing the value of  ?

Comment: for sure, i completely forgot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since we have the modulus and argument, we know that $z=-\sqrt3$, hence we get $-2iz=2\sqrt3i$.  The argument and modulus for that complex number are $\pi/2$ and $2\sqrt3$.

For explanation, the key is Euler's formula:  $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.  This allows us to identify every point $z=x+iy$ in the complex plane with a pair $(r,\theta)$, via $z=re^{i\theta}$..

Comment: The test result says the correct answer is $$modulus = 2\sqrt{3}$$ and $$argument= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Right.  I messed up.